# Setting the reactive data source from Route (Iron Router) is breaking reactivity

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have following code in the Router (Iron Router)

```
Router.map( function () {
this.route('hello',{path:'/hello',
onBeforeAction: function(){
console.log("QBConnected"+this.params.qbconnected);
Session.set("QBCONNECTED",this.params.qbconnected);
}
});

});
```

Following code in test.html

```
<template name="hello">
{{#if QBCONNECTED}}
<h1>Hello World if value={{QBCONNECTED}}</h1>
{{else}}
<h1>Hello World else value={{QBCONNECTED}}</h1>
{{/if}}
{{greeting}}
<input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

Following code in test.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
//Session.setDefault('QBCONNECTED',false);
Template.hello.greeting = function () {
return "Welcome to test.";
};

Template.hello.events({
'click input': function () {
// template data, if any, is available in 'this'
if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
console.log("You pressed the button");
}
});

Template.hello.QBCONNECTED=function(){
console.log(Deps.active+"get QBCONNECTED called"+Session.get('QBCONNECTED'));
return Session.get('QBCONNECTED');
};
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.startup(function () {
// code to run on server at startup
});
}
```

when I try to run this with the URL http://x.x.x.x:3000/hello?qbconnected=true

I see the string "Hello World if value=true" as expected
But when I try the url http://x.x.x.x:3000/hello?qbconnected=false, I see the string 
Hello World if value=false. Can anyone please explain why it is entering the if block when the value of QBCONNECTED is false?

When I try to set the value manually from browser console by "Session.set("QBCONNECTED",true)" it prints "Hello World if value=true" as expected but when I try "Session.set("QBCONNECTED",false)" it prints "Hello World else value= " , can any one explain why QBCONNECTED is loosing it's value when set to false ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `false` from your querystring gets evaluated to the `"false"` string and not false boolean value as you might have expected.